# Filter nil values from Clojure map?

Tags: dictionary, filter, clojure

What is the best way to filter `nil` values from a Clojure map `{}`?

```
{ :a :x :b nil :c :z }
;;=>  { :a :x, :c :z }
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I would use:

```
(into {} (filter (comp some? val) {:a :x, :b nil, :c :z}))

=> {:a :x, :c :z}
```

Doing the [some?](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/some_q) check explicitly is important because if you just do `(into {} (filter val {...}))` then you will erroneously remove values that are boolean false.

Comment: Or maybe `(into {} (remove (comp nil? val) {:a :x :b nil :c :z}))`

Comment: Yeah, the remove version is equivalent. In fact, remove is actually implemented in the Clojure source using filter, as: `(filter (complement pred) coll)`. Version with filter is marginally faster, version with remove is marginally shorter to type :-)

Comment: What about nested nil values?

Answer (score 5):

I use following code:

```
(into {} (filter val {:a 1, :b 2, :c nil}))
;;=> {:a 1, :b 2}
```

NOTE: this will remove false values as well as nils

Comment: this filters false out also :(

Comment: than u can use method decribed by mikera. But in most cases we have logic that nil means false and vv

Answer (score 4):

Probably not the best solution, but here's one that uses list comprehension:

```
(into {} 
  (for [[k v] {:a 1 :b nil :c :z} :when (not (nil? v))]
    [k v]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(into {} (keep (fn [e] (if (val e) e)) {:a :x :b nil :c :z}))
;;=> {:a :x, :c :z}
```

or a little shorter:

```
(into {} (keep #(if (val %) %) {:a :x :b nil :c :z}))
```

In fact, your filter suggestion is much better and shorter, so I would just use that:

```
(into {} (filter val {:a :x :b nil :c :z}))
```

Comment: Your function returns (:x :z) instead of {:a :x :c :z}

Answer (score -3):

The nicest way of doing this is actually`(into {} (keep second {:a :x :b nil}))`

Comment: (keep second {:a :x :b nil}) ==> (:x), `into` throw a exception.