# Can Cheshire omit keys without values?

Tags: json, clojure, cheshire

I'm using [Cheshire](https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire) to generate some JSON for data structures like this:

```
(require '[cheshire.core :refer [generate-string])
(generate-string {:id 123, :foo "something", :bar nil})
```

Which produces JSON like this:

```
{"id": 123, "foo": "something", "bar": null}
```

What I'd like is for the JSON to omit the keys without values; e.g.

```
{"id": 123, "foo": "something"}
```

Can Cheshire do this? I can certainly pre-filter the map before calling `generate-string`, but since Cheshire has to traverse my data structure anyway, I thought it would be more performant to instruct Cheshire to do the filtering.

Comment: No, `null` is a valid JSON value, so you should filter `nil` values yourself. [See this question for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339939/filter-nil-values-from-clojure-map).

Comment: Leonid, would you mind making your comment an answer? :)

Comment: I'm aware that null is a valid JSON value, and I certainly don't think this should be Cheshire's default behaviour. I think it would make a nice optional feature, kind of like running `(keyword)` on JSON keys as it's parsing.

Comment: @JoshGlover It definitely should not be the default behavior as it would mean re-parsing the JSON returns a different map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, null is a valid JSON value, so you should filter `nil` values yourself.

[See this question for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339939/filter-nil-values-from-clojure-map).

You may [propose this feature](https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire/issues) to Cheshire team.